# How to pass the value in SQL Server selected columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sorry it is my 1st to use stack overflow and I have a datagridview and only 3 columns I loaded from SQL Server:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/ 
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [employeesID], [firstName], [lastName], [middleName],
    [phoneNumber], [passCode], [EditDate], [DOB], [image] 
FROM 
    [PointofSale].[dbo].[employees]
```

I concat the `firstName` and `lastName` and I want to pass the value from SQL Server to a textbox. I don't know the logic.

```
public void datagridinsert()
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PointofSale.Properties.Settings.PointofSaleConnectionString"].ConnectionString; using (var con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open(); using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT employeesID, CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName, ' ', middleName) AS Name, createDate, designation FROM employees", con))
        {
           SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader(); 

           while (read.Read())
           {
                int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = read["employeesID"].ToString(); 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = read["Name"].ToString(); 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = read["createDate"].ToString(); 
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = read["designation"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is my 1st to use stack overflow and  i datagridview and only 3 columns i inserted from sql server /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [employeesID]
      ,[firstName]
      ,[lastName]
      ,[middleName]
      ,[phoneNumber]
      ,[passCode]
      ,[
      ,[EditDate]
      ,[DOB]
      ,[image]
  FROM [PointofSale].[dbo].[employees] i concact the firstName and last name and i want to pass the value from sql server to txtbox :( idon't know the logic it's been 3 days i search this problem

Comment: No problem. Please edit your post to add this comment and then delete it (I mean the comment).

Comment: @jdweng i have 8 textboxes and i was planning to pass all the value once i click the id from datagridview , i have 3 colums in datagridview but in sql server i have 8columns for textboxes for my update

Comment: You can handle the `DataGridView.CellClick` event to do that. Check if the clicked cell belongs to the `id` column through `if (e.ColumnIndex == idColumnIndex)` then get that row: `var r = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex];` and use `r.Cells[n].Value.ToString();` to populate your text boxes.